# How to save data from a textfield to a tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tableview, textfield

I'm working on my first app and I'm kind of new to Objective-C, I want to make it so when someone types in a `text field` then presses a button it will save it to a `table view`. Does anyone know how to do this or know any tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some good tutorials for you..

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/10/adding-uitableview-tutorial.html

Happy coding.

**EDIT:**

Here what i made for you:

[Simple Demo With TextField & TableView](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3PZzP2RSGt4WGZXTnVEUEdjNjg/edit?usp=drive_web)

**EDIT 2:**

[Simple Demo With 2 TextFields & 2 TableViews](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3PZzP2RSGt4WGZXTnVEUEdjNjg/edit?usp=drive_web)

Comment: is there any way to make that with multiple text fields and the textfields are on a different view than the table view

Comment: @JacobBanks, check for new demo.

Comment: @JacobBanks, `BaseViewController` is the class that we use for common methods. Please note that.

Comment: thank you so much. but since im kind of new i do not know alot abot xibs is there any way you could make it in storyboard. And in my app im making i am using storyboard

Comment: @JacobBanks, it doesn't matter about `storyboard` or `.xib` files. It is just the logic. it's the same in both scenarios. Just push & pop of pages are different. And believe me when you will be developing an app for some customer, you won't use `storyboard`. Because it will be too much complicated to do using it. But, if you use `.xib` files then things will be much easier for you. So i think that my answer is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is everytime you press the button you'll refresh/update your tableview.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
NSString *textNameToAdd = yourTextField.text;
[containerArrayForTableView addObject:textNameToAdd];
[myTableView reloadData];
}

// UITABLEVIEW DELEGATES
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
// Usually the number of items in your array (the one that holds your list)
return [containerArrayForTableView count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//Where we configure the cell in each row

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell... setting the text of our cell's label
cell.textLabel.text = [containerArrayForTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

refer [here](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2012/10/adding-uitableview-tutorial.html) if you are having trouble configuring with UITableView.

Comment: Thanks so much, but i am really new when i put this in my view controller.m i get 6 errors, do i have to put something in the .h

Comment: go to yout .h file add the UITableViewDelegate, something like this..
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

Comment: make sure you outlet your UITableViewDelegates also and your IBAction for UIButton. BTW if this help your question please up vote my answer..

Comment: check the link I mentioned in the above, its very simple and straight forward.